# build grid from 2 arrays in Ruby. Javascript to Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, grid

I'm trying to replicate a solution from javascript to Ruby where the idea is to build a grid from two arrays and then, running a search on both arrays, change certain elements in the grid.

I think my ruby solution is fairly similar but the grid doesn't look similar.

Any help is much appreciated

Arrays:
nums1 = [1,2,3,2,1]
nums2 = [3,2,1,4,7]

Javascript grid:

``
const dp = new Array(nums1.length + 1).fill(0).map(() => new Array(nums2.length + 1).fill(0));
console.log(dp)

```
  output: 
[
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]


Ruby grid attempts:
```

```
1º attempt

 dp = Array.new(nums1.length+1) {Array.new(nums2.length+1, 0)}
 p dp

2º attempt:
 dp = (0..n).map{|el| el = (0..m).to_a.map{|el| el = 0  }}
 p dp
```

```
  output is the same for both: 
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]



Thank you
```

Comment: The results of `Array.new(nums1.size+1) { Array.new(nums2.size+1, 0)  }` appear to be what you want. What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you want to prevent changes, `a = (Array.new(nums1.size+1) { Array.new(nums2.size+1, 0).freeze }).freeze`. Then `a[1] = [1,2,3]` and  `a[1][2] = 1` both raise the exception `FrozenError: can't modify frozen Array...`.